# white dots in grease pencil strokes

Tags: grease-pencil

I am working on animating with grease pencil, but have found it hard to display my work when there is a weird speckling of white throughout my stroke. The opacity of the palette stroke is set to 1.00, so I don't know what to do to fix it at this point.
[image]

Comment: Looks like you converted to geometry and those are the vertices?

Comment: No, those are pencil strokes. Let me make a gif to show what happens.

Answer (score 2):

The dots are transparent and the background shines through. Pretty sure the dots will change color if you turn the background red.

This happens when a very thick line style is used. GP seems to place lots of short stripes perpendicular to the stroke and the gaps happen when the strokes don't overlap. I tried 2.76 and the line was smooth and even. So some time after that, the way to draw GP has changed. Cranking up 'smooth' seems to help a bit, using a thinner stroke helps, too.

If you need really clean results, converting the strokes to a curve should work, giving it a bit of extrusion and a shadeless material. Sadly GP seems to connect all curves together, so a bit of cleanup is necessary.

[image: enlarged crop of the pencil brush style]

Comment: I tried basic brush, but got same result. For some reason, the strokes aren't really continuous.

Comment: I've tried on my other computer and you're right, any style is affected. I'm changing the answer

Comment: I hope they fix this in 2.8

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if yours is the same problem as mine, how my problem appears is when I draw over some imported bg video or bg image. The fix is go to camera properties-background image/video- depth: change from "back" to "front", then it solve my problem